# IBM Cognos Business Intelligence 10.2.1 for AIX yields a lot of 500 Internal Server Errors

Tags: aix, websphere, cognos

I am using IBM Cognos Business Intelligence 10.2.1 on WebSphere Application Server 7.0.0.37 for AIX 7.1.3.45 TL03. Every time my system undergoes a heavy usage period, which currently happens pretty often due to corporate end-of-quarter reporting, after about 15 minutes my dispatcher app locks up and displays a 500 Internal Server Error and I have to restart it. This didn't happen when the Cognos app on a server that is very similarly configured to the one we're currently using.

Any ideas on how to keep my Cognos app stable?

Answer (score 0):

Theres a hotfix for this:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM97420

If that doesn't resolve it, 500 Internal Server Errors a common problem on mainframes that run web-servers. Check to see if:

- The HTTP group PTF (SF99713) and/or the Java group PTF (SF99716) is backleveled
- The JVM that the ADMIN1, ADMIN2, ADMIN3, ADMIN4 and ADMIN5 jobs use is not functioning properly
- Symbolic links are missing from the IFS